# Exception on tableview row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, crash

I am having a **crash** on my app, that i can't reproduce, and even see something wrong on the log.

The actual implementation is like this :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if self.shoulHideDefaultCell {
        return .min
    }
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if self.shoulHideDefaultCell {
        return .min
    }
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

And the **error** i get is :

> Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
>           table view row height must not be negative - provided height for index path ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 0})
>   is -0.000000

The crash occurs only on iPhone5C or less, but my app is currently 9.3+.
Anyone have ever have this crash?

Comment: you can't pass the negative value to the heightForRowAtIndexPath. .min returned the minumum value of Int -922...

Comment: It tells you that you are returning negative value for height to some cells. Probably the `.min` value is negative on iPhone 5c or older devices.

Comment: But i already used that value on heightForHeader, or Footer, the problem is only on heightForRowAtIndexPath. I set the value to hardcode 0. Trying to reproduce the problem.

Comment: What happens when the height is set to 0? Does it crash also?